# Deriving $\mathbf{\left ( I - G_{0} \right )^{-1} A^{p}}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-verification, matrix-equations

I have the following set of equations:
 \begin{align}
 u_{s}=-\beta \left ( u_{on} - u_{br}\right ) + \gamma u_{l} + v_{s},
 \end{align}
 \begin{align}
 u_{l}=\lambda \left ( u_{on} - u_{br} \right ) + v_{l},
 \end{align}
 \begin{align}
 u_{a}=\phi_{l}v_{l} + \phi_{s}v_{s} + v_{a}.
 \end{align}
    Assume $u_{br} = 0$ and $u_{a} = u_{l} + u_{s}$.
 Rewrite the model in the form 
 \begin{align}
 \mathbf{\left ( I - G_{0} \right ) u^{p} = A^{p}v^{p}}.
 \end{align}
 Substitute out $u_{s}$ in equation (1) to get
 $$\mathbf{\left ( I - G_{0} \right ) u^{p}} = \begin{bmatrix}
  (1-\gamma) &1  &\beta \\ 
  0&1  &0 \\ 
  1&0  &-\lambda 
 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
 u_{l}\\ 
 u_{a}\\ 
 u_{on}
\end{bmatrix}.$$

Also, $$\mathbf{A^{p}v^{p}} = \begin{bmatrix}
0 &0  &1 \\ 
\phi_{s} &1  &\phi_{l} \\ 
1&0  &0 
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
v_{l}\\ 
v_{a}\\ 
v_{s}
\end{bmatrix}.$$

**EDIT:** The determinant of $\mathbf{\left ( I - G_{0} \right )} = \lambda \left ( 1 - \gamma \right ) - \beta,$
and using the method of determinants and cofactors, 
$$\mathbf{\left ( I - G_{0} \right )^{-1}} = \frac{1}{\lambda\left ( 1 - \gamma \right ) - \beta} \begin{bmatrix}
-\lambda &\lambda  &-\beta \\ 
0&-\lambda\left ( 1-\gamma \right )-\beta  &0 \\ 
-1&1  &1-\gamma  
\end{bmatrix}.$$

After some tedious matrix algebra, I find that 
$$\mathbf{\left ( I - G_{0} \right )^{-1} A^{p}v^{p}} = \frac{1}{\lambda\left ( 1 - \gamma \right ) - \beta} \begin{bmatrix}
\phi_{s} \lambda - \beta&\lambda  & \lambda\left ( \phi_{l} - 1 \right )\\ 
\phi_{s}\left ( -\lambda\left ( 1-\gamma \right )- \beta \right )&-\lambda\left ( 1-\gamma \right )-\beta  & \phi_{l}\left ( -\lambda\left ( 1-\gamma \right )- \beta \right )\\ 
\phi_{s}-1-\gamma&1  &\phi_{l}-1  
\end{bmatrix},$$
and
 \begin{align*}
 u^{p} = \begin{bmatrix}
 u_{l} &u_{a}  &u_{on} 
 \end{bmatrix}^{'},
 \end{align*}
 \begin{align*}
 v^{p} = \begin{bmatrix}
 v_{l} &v_{a}  &v_{s} 
 \end{bmatrix}^{'}.
 \end{align*}
What I am having trouble with is how the expression below was obtained or what result is correct.

\begin{align*}
 \mathbf{\left ( I - G_{0} \right )^{-1} A^{p}} = \frac{1}{\lambda (\gamma -1)}\begin{bmatrix}
 \beta -\lambda \phi_{l}  &-\gamma   & \lambda \left ( 1 - \phi _{s} \right )\\ 
 \phi_{l}\left ( \beta + \lambda \left ( \gamma -1 \right ) \right )&\beta + \lambda \left ( \gamma -1 \right )  &\phi_{s}\left ( \beta + \lambda \left ( \gamma -1 \right ) \right )  \\ 1 - \gamma - \phi_{l} 
 &-1  &1 - \phi_{s}  
 \end{bmatrix},
 \end{align*}
  and 
 \begin{align*}
 u^{p} = \begin{bmatrix}
 u_{l} &u_{a}  &u_{o} 
 \end{bmatrix}^{'},
 \end{align*}
 \begin{align*}
 v^{p} = \begin{bmatrix}
 v_{l} &v_{a}  &v_{s} 
 \end{bmatrix}^{'}.
 \end{align*}

Do I have the correct result of deriving $\mathbf{\left ( I - G_{0} \right )^{-1} A^{p}}$?

Comment: I've made an edit.